# WebRTC y Licode para salas de chat

Tags: javascript

Hasta ahora nunca he trabajado con WebRTC y me veo en la situación de tener que hacer una aplicación de video/audio conferencia con múltiples participantes. En concreto, se ha de manejar un número de salas N con un moderador y hasta 12 participantes.

En un principio se calcula que estarán activas simultáneamente 10 salas como máximo (N=10). Esto establece un pico de 120 conexiones simultáneas. Sería deseable que fuera escalable para en un futuro poder manejar más salas de manera simultánea.

En los pocos días que llevo informándome sobre este asunto, he visto que necesitaría un servidor STUNT/TURN para manejar todo el entramado de señalización, penetración de NAT, etc.

Después de buscar distintas soluciones, creo que Licode se adapta más o menos bien a mi situación. Aunque hay otras soluciones más completas, parece que también son más complejas.

Ahora me encuentro instalando Licode en una máquina virtual con Ubuntu 20.04 y estoy encontrando muchos problemas, por lo que aún no lo he podido probar.

Si hay alguien que tenga experiencia en este terreno, me gustaría saber qué posibilidades tiene Licode para manejar esta carga de trabajo y sus posibilidades de escalado.

Por otro lado, el servidor podría ser local o alojado en un centro de datos. Este servidor sólo funcionará durante algunas horas al día y no es un sistema 24x7, por lo que la opción de un servidor local con fibra de 300 o 600M podría ser viable, al menos inicialmente. Sin embargo, me preocupa el ancho de banda. ¿Qué ancho de banda podría ser necesario para la carga comentada más arriba?

Por último, ¿qué configuración de hardware sería adecuada?, procesador, memoria, disco.

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta se basa totalmente en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. Saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo visitar [WebRTC experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/), hay muy buenos ejemplos de lo que quieres hacer.